# ¿Cómo se declara la variable global mCurrentLocation?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

Buenas tardes compañeros.
Estoy siguiendo el manual de android para obtener una ubicación en tiempo real, pero hay un fragmento del manual que no entiendo aún y dice:

"La ubicación conocida más reciente del dispositivo proporciona una base práctica de inicio y garantiza que la app tenga una ubicación conocida antes de comenzar con las actualizaciones de ubicación periódicas. La lección sobre cómo obtener la última ubicación conocida te muestra cómo realizar el proceso llamando a getLastLocation(). En los fragmentos de las siguientes secciones se asume que la app ya obtuvo la última ubicación conocida y la almacenó como un objeto Location en la variable global mCurrentLocation."

Mi pregunta es, ¿como puedo declarar y donde, esa variable? y ¿de que tipo sería ya que almacena dos datos? o ¿no es asi?

Gracias, dejo el link de la seccion del manual.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

UPDATE:
Creo que debi aclarar un poco mas la pregunta, lo siento. Quiero declararla de forma global, ya que estoy usando varios fragments.

Muchas gracias me sirvieron mucho sus comentarios... ya lo pude hacer

Comment: Como? Location mCurrentLocation; Donde? donde vos quieras. Tipo? Location, no solo tiene dos campos sino un monton de cosas.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

Comment: Crea un Singleton mCurrentLocation adentro de él. Despues podes llamar al singleton desde el fragment que quieras y recuperar la location. Aca un ejemplo de como hacer un singleton https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-to-make-the-perfect-singleton-de6b951dfdb0